# Detect whether the device is phone, tablet or tv on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know whether the used device is tv or not..I am using flutter_device_type package but it only detects the tablet and consider any other device as  phone

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package for detecting Android TV.

The [AndroidDeviceInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/device_info_plus_platform_interface/latest/model_android_device_info/AndroidDeviceInfo-class.html) class contains a [list of all the system's features](https://pub.dev/documentation/device_info_plus_platform_interface/latest/model_android_device_info/AndroidDeviceInfo/systemFeatures.html) as documented in the [Android PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager)

For detecting TV, you can use e.g:

```dart
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
bool isTV = androidInfo.systemFeatures.contains('android.software.leanback')
```

Comment: it works, big thanks for this answer. IMO ShortestSide from MediaQuery will give same result if device is tablet or Smart TV.

Comment: This does not work for the Amazon Fire TV stick. `android.software.leanback` should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

By default flutter detects the device based on its minimum size(screens bigger than a minimum width considered as a tablet), something like this code:

```
  String getDeviceType() {
    final data = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window);
    return data.size.shortestSide < 600 ? 'phone' :'tablet';
  }
```

In another hand with Java/Kotlin and based on [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#runtime-check) you can detect if the device is android Tv with this code:

```
val uiModeManager = getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
if (uiModeManager.currentModeType == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device")
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device")
}
```

So the proper option would be using a native code and connecting it to flutter using [platform-channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Answer (score 0):

To detect Android TV you can detect the presence of leanback launcher without additional packages.

First modify `android\app\src\main\kotlin\MainActivity.kt` like so:

```
package [your package here]

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "android.tv"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
        call, result ->
            if(!isLeanbackLauncherDevice()) {
                result.success(false)
            } else {
                result.success(true)
            }
        }
    }

    fun isLeanbackLauncherDevice(): Boolean {
        val pm = this.getPackageManager()  
        if (pm.hasSystemFeature("PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK")) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
  
}
```

Then call it from your app like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const platform = MethodChannel('android.tv');
Future<bool> isAndroidTv() async {
  final bool isTv = await platform.invokeMethod('isLeanbackLauncherDevice');
  return isTv;
}
```